# Determine the number of point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(z-2)^4=(1+i)^4$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm new in Real Analysis, and I'm stuck as I would like to determine the number of point $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(z-2)^4=(1+i)^4$.

I might transform $z$ in $re^{i\alpha}$, but I don't know how to proceed. 
Can someone help me explaining in detail the steps? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you talk about Real Analysis and then you post a question which is neither about Analysis nor about real numbers?

Comment: My bad, I typed wrong. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

- $w=(1+i)^4$

then evaluate

$$(z-2)^4=w$$

Comment: Thank you, but that's exactly where I'm stuck at. I tried $w=(z-2)^4$.

Comment: @KevinMoore What is $w$?

Comment: @KevinMoore What I mean is that $w=(1+i)^4$ is just a particular number (we need to evaluate it at first) therefore the problem reduces to calculate $(z-2)^4=w$ which is almost trivial.

Comment: @KevinMoore Can you evaluate $(1+i)^4$?

Comment: Yes, I solved it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @KevinMoore Well done! You are welcome! Nothing special as you can see now. Bye

Answer (score 3):

$$(z-2/1+i )^4=1=e^{2n\pi i}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$(z-2)/(1+i)=e^{2n\pi i /4}$ where $n=0,1,2,3$

Comment: Very nice and clever way!

Answer (score 2):

Basically:
$$(1+i)^4=(z-2)^4 \to z-2=\pm 1 \pm i $$

Should be easy from there

Answer (score 2):

You said you want the *number* of points, not their exact location.

For you may note that the original equation is a polynomial equation $P(z)=0$ of degree $4$.

The derivative $P^\prime(z)$ is $4(z-2)^3$ which has $z=2$ has the only zero with multiplicity $3$. Since $z=2$ is not a root of $P(z)$ the original equation has $4$ different solutions.